# validation of an input type email with css, without javascript

Tags: css, validation, email, input

How can you validate an input type email with css without using javascript?
I am a newbie and I have no idea on how to do it

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could either accept my answer, or let me know if there is something missing from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with HTML. Basically, the pattern allows you to use regex to specify what is an "allowable" input. If you try to submit, it will be flagged. Here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

And here is a code fragment:

```
<input type="text" name="email"
  pattern=".*@.*\..*" title="valid email address">
```

The regex for email validation should **not** be over complicated. Many things can be valid emails. Pretty much anything that contains an @ symbol and a dot after the @ symbol can be an email (this is what the regex I provided checks for) and (on a technical level) even those two features are not necessarily required.

Fun fact: If you own a Top Level Domain (let's say .com for illustrative purposes) and you have been running a legacy email server on it since the 90s and haven't updated it to modern standards, then you can technically have an email that is just "com".